# Timestamp in RxJS 5.0

Tags: rxjs5

In RxJS 4.0 I could do something as follows:

```
let clicks = Observable.fromEvent(board.canvas, 'click'),
    keydowns = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
      .filter((e) => e.keyCode === 32);
  return Observable
    .merge(clicks, keydowns)
    .sample(200).
    .timestamp();
```

[Now that RxJS 5.0 dropped support for `timestamp`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md), how would this piece of code be done in the migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers - 
`.timestamp()` has been re-implemented in RxJS 5.0 (in beta.4 (2016-03-29)).

Changelog at: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

We can recreate this behavior fairly easily by mapping over some source Observable:

```
function timestamp(source) {
    return source.map(value => ({ value, timestamp: Date.now() }));
}
```

And in your code:

```
let clicks = Observable.fromEvent(board.canvas, 'click');
let keydowns = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
      .filter((e) => e.keyCode === 32);

let clicksAndKeydowns = Observable
    .merge(clicks, keydowns)
    .sample(200);

return timestamp(clicksAndKeydowns);
```